# Getting the selected object position of a JComboBox

Tags: java, swing, drop-down-menu, jcombobox

I'm trying to get the position (as a int) of a JComboBox object, The ComboBox is generated and haves an action listener like this

```
for (int d=0; d<i; d++)
        {
            titulos.addItem(listaPraBox[d]);
        }

  ActionListener comboListener = new ActionListener() {
          public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
            ItemSelectable is =(ItemSelectable)actionEvent.getSource();     
            objectoseleccionado = selectedString(is);
            DeskMetodos.listaTexto(objectoseleccionado);        
          }
        };
    titulos.addActionListener(comboListener);
```

The executes

```
 static private String selectedString(ItemSelectable is) {
    Object selected[] = is.getSelectedObjects();

    return ((selected.length == 0) ? "null" : (String)selected[0]);
  }
```

But I wanted the position of the selected object to get a string from another array by that int.

Is this even possible? By the search I've made there isn't even reference to this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`JComboBox` defines [`getSelectedIndex()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JComboBox.html#getSelectedIndex%28%29).  The implementation is just to loop over the data model checking equality with `getSelectedItem()`.

That doesn't make it up into `ItemSelectable`, but neither does the data model itself, so you may need to use the concrete class.

Comment: Could you explain me the concrete class? Didn't quite understood what that means.

In the eclipse it gives me the option off add(Component comp, Index int). Can the component be a string from x position of the array?

Comment: By "concrete class", I mean you may need to use `JComboBox` in your listener code instead of `ItemSelectable`.

Comment: for JComboBox would be better look for ItemListener, +1

Comment: Ok, I got the idea and I successfully implemented it. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Instead of storing items in a ComboBox and having to use the index to reference another array of values. Just store an object in the ComboBox that has a `toString()` output that matches your current displayed value and a direct reference to the object in the array.  That way any object pulling the selected item or dealing with comobo box can just pull the value they need and not have to also "know" about this other array.

Comment: The problem with that method would be the repeated names(i think), that's why i needed the i position. Got it now. But I thank you for the insight.

Comment: @Lucky, this would solve the repeat names issue because each position would have a different object with the correct value regardless of the description.